Assertion error when insering large sized data into a spawned process using multiprocessing with queue
I'm trying to spawn a new process and run a certain function with it that uses cupy to preform heavy computations on the GPU.
Each process have the following worker instance (code snippet not the full class):
class Worker(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, gpu_id: int, in_q: Queue, res_q: Queue):
        super().__init__()
        self.gpu_id = gpu_id
        self.in_q = in_q
        self.res_q = res_q
   
    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                with cp.cuda.Device(self.gpu_id):
                    buffer = self.in_q.get()
                    res = func(buffer)
                    self.res_q.put(res)
            except queue.Empty:
                break

The problem is when I'm putting large buffers in the queue (above 2GB) I'm getting an Assertion Error
with output:
buffer = self.in_queue.get() # From my code
res = self._recv_bytes() # From Lib\multiprocessing\queues.py
res = self._recv_bytes(maxlength) # From Lib\multiprocessing\connection.py
return self._get_more_data(ov, maxsize) # From Lib\multiprocessing\connection.py
assert left > 0 # From Lib\multiprocessing\connection.py
AssertionError

I could use cp.asarray(buffer) before passing it to the queue and the res_q will handle only pointers to the resulted data on the GPU, and only the main process will call cp.asnumpy(res) but I want to know if there is a fix for that.
python version - 3.11.3
